# Xcode 5.0.1 crashes after Run

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5.0.1

Good day! I have strange problem with Xcode 5.0.1. When I'm trying to run the app - it crashes with the following exception: UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): must provide a file handle or pipe

I have also reinstalled Xcode (from the app store) and I have still obtained the same result.

Comment: Have you searched?  I'm sure there are lots of questions like this (and precious little in terms of answers).  That's because there isn't much you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when updating from 5.0.0 to 5.0.1. The fix was that I was using 10.9 DP1. Now having 10.9, the final version and a fresh xcode install, it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

i have facing same problem but with little change resolve my issues.
Change littile syntex like as show below

```
-(void)SelectBg;
```

change to

`-(void)SelectBg:(id)sender`;

Thanks and happy coding